# resizing an in-line list depending on screen size

Tags: html, css, resize, center, resolution

I am trying to get a menu at the top of page to be centered regardless of the resolution of screen it is being viewed on, but however am having some issues in getting this done.  I have been trying to resize font size or even image size based on resolution, in order to fit the list on top but have not had any luck.

This is the code I currently have:

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  background: url("Images/lightbackground.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}


/* unvisited link */

a:link {
  color: red;
}


/* visited link */

a:visited {
  color: green;
}


/* mouse over link */

a:hover {
  color: hotpink;
}


/* selected link */

a:active {
  color: blue;
}

#HeaderMenu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 145px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  color: blue;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: DarkKhaki;
  position: fixed;
}

#HeaderMenu ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  list-style: none;
}

#HeaderMenu li {
  float: left;
}

#HeaderMenu a {
  padding: 0 14px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

#HeaderMenu ul li a.logo {
  background-image: url("Images/red_transparent.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 140px;
  display: block;
  width: 215px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  padding: 0;
}

footer {
  padding: 10px;
  color: blue;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: black;
}

.BodySection {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("Images/wood.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-size: contain;
}

article {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 5000px;
}

nav ul {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-width: 0px 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 15px;
}

nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

h2 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.HeaderImageSection {
  padding-top: 137px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-right: 100px;
}

.HeaderImage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background-image: url('Images/image.jpg');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Black Han Sans">

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        </script>
        <![endif]-->

<body>

  <header>

    <div id="HeaderMenu" style="font-family: Black Han Sans;">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="test.html">Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="test.html">Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="test.html">Test</a></li>
        <li>
          <a class="logo" href="index.html"></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="test.html">Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="test.html">Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="test.html">Test</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </header>

  <div class="HeaderImageSection">
    <div class="HeaderImage"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="BodySection">
    <section>

      <h2>Home</h2>
      <article>
        <h3>COMING SOON....</h3>
      </article>
    </section>
  </div>

</body>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try changing your ul or the parent div to a width of, say 80%.  Then margin-left: 10%.  Or width: 60% / margin-left: 20%.

Comment: Try to use bootstrab https://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: @user2796515 Actually that does seem to center it on the laptop I am working on.  However, when I go to it on something smaller, like a mobile device, it is then too far left.  Definitely getting closer....

Thanks!

Comment: @WaelAbbas I will take a look at it, but this should be possible using CSS I would think.

Comment: possible but bootstrap is easy to use, responsive and mobile-first and it's not easy to do that from scratch it

Comment: @WaelAbbas Thank you!  I will try it out and see if I can reoslve my issue easier using it.  I've been driving myself crazy all day moving things around and resizing trying to get it just right.

Comment: @burton963 There may be another css rule that prevents it from working.  That along with the other static rules using pixels - just a thought.

Comment: Thank you for all the help @WaelAbbas and @user2796515!  I was able to get everything positioned as wanted using bootstrap, and it also enabled me to create some nice mobile features.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)  specially [Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/) component for menu purposes.

> - Bootstrap is a free front-end framework for faster and easier web development
> - Bootstrap includes HTML and CSS based design templates for typography, forms, buttons, tables, navigation, modals, image
>     carousels and many other, as well as optional JavaScript plugins
> - Bootstrap also gives you the ability to easily create responsive designs

What is Responsive Web Design?

> Responsive web design is about creating web sites which automatically
>   adjust themselves to look good on all devices, from small phones to
>   large desktops.

Answer (score 0):

As Wael Abbas said earlier, you should get a look to Bootstrap Navbar [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)

For a quick answer I build for you a simple navbar with the following code:

You can just copy/paste him into your html page and then you're able to adapt it to your request !

```html
    <head>
        <!-- bootstrap CDN -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    
    </head>
    
    
    <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
    </body>
```

Let me know if you have any questions !